Ddclient updates main domain always
Ddclient configuration:
# Configuration file for ddclient

syslog=yes
verbose=yes

use=web
web=dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com/getip
web-skip='IP Address'
ssl=yes
protocol=dyndns2
server=dyndns.[removed]

login=[removed]
password=[removed]

# Domain
www.site.com
site.com

There is domain with www and without. The www one is cached but the one without www is always updated.
Log file:
RECEIVE:
RECEIVE:  e
RECEIVE:  [IP]
RECEIVE:  0
RECEIVE:
SUCCESS:  www.site.com: skipped: IP address was already set to [IP].
INFO:     setting IP address to [IP] for site.com
UPDATE:   updating site.com
CONNECT:  dyndns.....

I think it started with update to 24.04.1 but not sure. Does anyone know why?
I tried to delete cache but still the same problem.

Seems like problem as https://github.com/ddclient/ddclient/issues/601 but its not 11 version. Maybe ubuntu uses some merged version? IDk I fixed it by manually adding IP to ddclient cache file.
